# Selecting from amongst mutiple WCF service references

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I was wondering what the best course of action would be for selecting an/or switching between a set of service calls to different end-points in a single application. Right now, I have a very cludgy system where I have mutiple applications (.exe's) each with a different code to run against its required service.

I tried putting multiple endpoints in the app.config but it messes up the system and there are runtime exceptions.

Thank you !

Comment: What are those runtime exceptions? You'll need to post your configurations in order to get any kind of meaningful feedback on this issue.

Comment: When I try to put multiple endpoints corresponding to the different endpoints I want to hit, I get the error "Sections must only appear once per config file".

Comment: So that's not what you should do, then. To see what multiple endpoints in one config file looks like, you may want to create a dummy WCF project with multiple endpoints.

Comment: Correct. But for running against a particular endpoint, I would have to comment out the other client XML sections  <client>
        <endpoint address="https://URL"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_CompositeMemberServiceContract"
            contract="CompositeService.SVC"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_CompositeMemberService" />  I was thinking of finding a way to select a client config at runtime depending on whick service I am invoking.

Comment: You shouldn't have to - you can have multiple endpoints in the same client section - they just can't have the same name and address, e.g. <client> <endpoint address="http://1.2.3.4/dummy1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="dummy1" name="Dummy1" /> <endpoint address="http://1.2.3.4/dummy2" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="dummy2" name="Dummy2" /> </client>